# How to copy data from one table to another same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a master database and several child databases on the same server and all the databases have identical tables. I have to copy data from master to child databases but on each child database there's going to be different data from the tables.

Right now, I'm selecting data, comparing it and inserting / deleting it using PHP, which was working fine when there were only 2-3 child databases, but now as the child databases are growing the copying is getting slower.

I even tried to replicate the database tables using the following queries though it worked but later I realized that child dB's don't need all master data, rather they require some specific data only.

```
TRUNCATE master_db.papers;
INSERT INTO child_1.papers SELECT * FROM master_db.papers;
```

The above copies all the database based on WHERE condition. but after understanding all the requirements, I have to do the following:

I also tried replacing INSERT with UPDATE but that is causing mysql error.

1. Copy anything that may have updated in the master to child (UDPATE ONLY)
2. Copy any new data that needs to go into child.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I'm lost -- Do you want the child table to match the parent, then you say it does not.  Will there be missing rows?  Extra rows?  Changed columns in some rows?  What?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out using the following:

Incase you want to copy all data from source to destination:

```
INSERT INTO source_db.source_table SELECT * FROM target_db.target_table WHERE some_condition = '0';
```

And if you want to update according to the target table:

```
UPDATE target_db.target_table 
INNER JOIN source_db.source_table USING (some_field) SET 
target_db.target_table.id = source_db.source_table.id,
target_db.target_table.name = source_db.source_table.name,
target_db.target_table.phone = source_db.source_table.phone;
```

Hope this helps anyone is looking to do similar task.